# what difference is there between undefined and null?

Tags: javascript

Most blogs say that undefined type is a state of allocated on memory but not having any value and null type is a state of allocated on memory having a null value.

however I think in case of a.js file.

a.js includes 
console.log(typeof tmp);

and It may print undefined.
but In a.js file, var tmp is not declared.
so I guess tmp variable is not allocated on memory but It is showed as undefined.

why does that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value. On the other hand, null is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a representation of no value.
Also, undefined and null are two distinct types: undefined is a type itself (undefined) while null is an object.
Unassigned variables are initialized by JavaScript with a default value of undefined. JavaScript never sets a value to null. That must be done programmatically.

reference: http://www.ajaymatharu.com/javascript-difference-between-undefined-and-null/